# Margin under ConstraintLayout guideline not appearing properly

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to add some space underneath the `Guideline` for my constraint layout, but for some reason it doesn't appear to be applied. Does anyone know what is going on and how to apply 5dp of margin underneath the `Guideline` (for both portrait and landscape orientations)?

**XML layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightgrey">
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map_townmap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#09c"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSun"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sun_black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/switch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewSun"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewMoon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMoon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_moon_black"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/switch"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Portrait orientation**

[image]

**Portrait orientation (close-up)**

[image]

**Landscape orientation**

[image]

**Landscape orientation (close-up)**

[image]

Comment: You can't apply margins to a `Guideline`, refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html)

Comment: @Kiya What CAN be done to solve this then?

Comment: Why are you using it in the first place?

Comment: @Kiya This layout previously had a PercentRelativeLayout, which is now deprecated.

Comment: You could use a `LinearLayout` with weights.

Comment: Interestingly I did try this before, but then that means I would have to put the images and switch in its own LinearLayout hence nested layouts are not recommended.

Comment: Hmm did you try adding marginBottom to the parent `ConstraintLayout` ?

Comment: I did but didn't work. I'll stick to LinearLayout's thanks for your help

Answer (score 10):

You can apply margins to Guidelines:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="5dp" />
```

Although you might need to adjust the margin `layout_constraintGuide_begin`  and the `android:orientation` accordingly. Probably you should do that though a portrait layout xml file and a landscape layout xml file in their correct res folder locations.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the thing is you have added `Guideline` and you are using `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9"`. This means that `Guideline` will be set according to the parent layout, so when you change orientation it will look weird.

Use following code to solve your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightgrey">
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map_townmap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#09c"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewSun"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSun"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sun_black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_stationmap_lighttheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/switch" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_stationmap_lighttheme"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewSun"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewMoon"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMoon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_moon_black"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_stationmap_lighttheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/switch"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @MacaronLover - In the future you should explain code changes when suggesting edits. When looking at an edit to an answer we don't actually see the question in the review queue.